# Difference between echos with row and not

Tags: php, mysql

Since I have been learning PHP and MySQL, I notice sometimes I see `echo $row['name']` and `<?php echo $variable ?>`. What is the difference between them? Is it all the same, or there is something different between these type of display info? Why do some people use row and others not?

Comment: Do you mean to ask what the difference is between `$row['name']` and `$row["name"]`?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but `$row['name']` is accessing an array

Comment: @sachleen: Be careful editing questions for syntax that are *about* syntax.

Comment: @WesleyMurch OP had wrapped the code statements in quotes.. I don't think that was the question. The title also supports my thinking. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: @sachleen: Better to ask than assume, it could very well have been the essence of the question.

Answer (score 1):

When the mysql result is returned in an array, it's commonly just called `$row`. So you have all of the returned columns in the `$row` variable and reference them as `$row['id']`, `$row['title']`, `$row['whatever']`.

`echo $id;` is simply echoing the `$id` variable.

Both just echo a variable, it's just that the first one echos an item from an array and the second one is just a variable named `$id`.

Comment: yes, its kind confuse because sometimes i see that is made differente ways but whit the same feature, for example i want to display some name of the table database, i can make this way:

$sql_view= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name");
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($sql_view)){
$name= $line ['name'];
echo $name;

but here doest is different way,http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

I wonder what of these 2 are more effective or better.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array, so you have to reference the field in the array. In your example, `echo $name` just echos the single variable `$name`. That is not coming from the `mysql_fetch_array`. They're just two completely different variables. One is an array, the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

$row['name'] accesses an associative array ($row) by key (name)

$id is just a variable

Answer (score 1):

`echo "$row['name']"` is accessing an element in an array

`<?php echo $id ?>` is (likely) accessing a variable.

These are 2 different things

Answer (score 0):

`$row['name']` indexes into an array, while `$name` would just reference the variable 'name'

```
$name = "foo";

$row = array(
    'name' => 'bar'
);

echo $row['name']; //prints bar
echo $name; //prints foo
```